# Model fit VS R-square in path analysis

Tags: path-model

This is more a conceptual problem, as path analysis (without latent variable) is basically regressions, can I say the model fit indices is something similar to the F value?

Usually in regression, larger F have larger R^2. However, I have path analysis that have larger R^2 yet the fit indices were poorer. Why is this so? Can this be explained just by concepts?

Comment: What fit indices are you looking at?

Comment: @le_andrew, RMSEA, TLI...